# Permission problems when creating a dir with os.makedirs in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm simply trying to handle an uploaded file and write it in a working dir which name is the system timestamp. The problem is that I want to create that directory with full permission (**777**) but I can't! Using the following piece of code the created directory with **755** permissions.

```
def handle_uploaded_file(upfile, cTimeStamp):
    target_dir = "path_to_my_working_dir/tmp_files/%s" % (cTimeStamp)
    os.makedirs(target_dir, mode=0777)
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I simply get the directory but with the wrong permissions (755 instead of 777).

Comment: Whatever it is you are hoping to accomplsh, **`chmod 0777` is *wrong* and insecure** and you should revert to sane permissions immediately, or in the worst case reinstall your system if you cannot be sure that users who should not be able to overwrite system files haven't abused the security hole you created.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

According to the official python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) the mode argument of the `os.makedirs` function may be ignored on some systems, and on systems where it is not ignored the current umask value is masked out.

Either way, you can force the mode to 0o777 (0777 threw up a syntax error) using the `os.chmod` function.

Comment: +1: `umask` is often the culprit when unexpected permissions show up.

Comment: I agree, the problem is probably umask - this diagnoses is probably not correct.

Comment: @dbw I am inclined to agree that the current umask setting is probably the cause of the problem, which is why I mentioned the umask in my answer - before describing an alternate solution using chmod.

Comment: >>0777 threw up a syntax error: 
Did you run this in a py3 environment? Octal representation has changed in py3.

Comment: Need `os.umask(0)` before, to remove the mask for the current user. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67723702/8718377

Answer (score 45):

You are running into problems because os.makedir() honors the umask of current process ([see the docs, here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs)).  If you want to ignore the umask, you'll have to do something like the following:

```py
import os
try:
    original_umask = os.umask(0)
    os.makedirs('full/path/to/new/directory', desired_permission)
finally:
    os.umask(original_umask)
```

In your case, you'll want to `desired_permission` to be `0777` (octal, not string).  Most other users would probably want 0755 or 0770.

Comment: Slight correction: umask is not a property of files or directories, it is set by the running process. Usually the umask is inherited from the shell.

Comment: Thanks, sundae - verifying and updating.

Comment: @dbw Wow, things works as expected by changing umask :) BUT Is there any risk of doing that?

Comment: I would like create directory inside /var. But if i tried above code i am facing Permission denied: '/var/test'

Comment: @Manjunath - your user needs to have permission to write in the parent folder. Usually only root has write permission in `/var`.

Comment: Shouldn't the `original_umask = os.umask(0)` line be outside (just before) the try block?  Otherwise if it raises, the `finally` block may have unintended results.

Comment: For py3 environments, 0XYZ (octal numbers) would have to be written as 0oXYZ.

Answer (score 15):

For Unix systems (when the mode is not ignored) the provided mode is first masked with **umask** of current user. You could also fix the **umask** of the user that runs this code. Then you will not have to call `os.chmod()` method. 
Please note, that if you don't fix **umask** and create more than one directory with `os.makedirs` method, you will have to identify created folders and apply `os.chmod` on them.

For me I created the following function:

```
def supermakedirs(path, mode):
    if not path or os.path.exists(path):
        return []
    (head, tail) = os.path.split(path)
    res = supermakedirs(head, mode)
    os.mkdir(path)
    os.chmod(path, mode)
    res += [path]
    return res
```

Comment: I am unable to create 'test' directory inside '/var/' .

Comment: I tried *many* things - this is the only way that actually worked on `macOS`

Answer (score 6):

The other anwsers did not worked for me (with python **2.7**).

I had to add `os.umask(0)` before, to remove the mask for the current user. And I had to change the mode from `0777` to `0o777`:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(upfile, cTimeStamp):
    target_dir = "path_to_my_working_dir/tmp_files/%s" % (cTimeStamp)
    os.umask(0)
    os.makedirs(path, mode=0o777)
```