# python3 os.mkdir() does not enforce correct mode

Tags: python-3.x, mkdir

Is it a bug or a feature ?

When I create a directory with `os.mkdir` (idem with `pathlib.Path.mkdir`) and an explicit mode, the permissions of the created directory does not fit. If I enforce with `os.chmod` again, it works...

```
>>> import sys, os
>>> sys.version
'3.4.3 (default, Feb 27 2015, 18:13:37) \n[GCC 4.4.5]'
>>> os.mkdir('truite', mode=0o2770)
>>> oct(os.stat('truite').st_mode)
'0o40750'
>>> os.chmod('truite', 0o2770)
>>> oct(os.stat('truite').st_mode)
'0o42770'
```

---

since I wanted to be able to make a directory with parents and mode o2770, here is the code (`pth` is a `pathlib.Path` object) :

```
def make_shared_dir(pth) :
    if not pth.parent.is_dir() :
        make_shared_dir(pth.parent)
    if not pth.is_dir() :
        pth.mkdir()
    pth.chmod(0o2770)
```

Comment: confirmed wit Ubuntu 14.04, Python 3.4.3. According to the docs: On some systems, mode is ignored.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission problems when creating a dir with os.makedirs (python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231901/permission-problems-when-creating-a-dir-with-os-makedirs-python)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a feature.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkdir) mentions it, albeit briefly:

> `os.mkdir(path[, mode])`
>
> Create a directory named path with numeric mode mode. The default mode is 0777 (octal). On some systems, mode is ignored. **Where it is used, the current umask value is first masked out.**

A [umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) is a per-process setting that limits the permissions applied to all newly created files/directories.

A umask is a number (usually presented in octal) just like permissions themselves, but any bit that is **set** in the umask is **disallowed** in the resulting permissions. For example, if your umask is `0o022` (a common default), no newly created file/directory will ever have group or world write permissions.

Permissions on newly created files/directories are also always restricted to the last three octal digits (i.e. `0o777`). So if your umask is `0o022`, everything behaves as if it were really `0o7022`.
This is why your setgid bit is also dropped.

By the way, this is not a Python thing; it's a Unix thing. It doesn't just apply to Python, but to all programs in Ubuntu. You can check your current umask by entering the `umask` command in your terminal. In fact, the umask is enforced by the Linux kernel when it performs the `mkdir()` systemcall that Python (and every other program) invokes to create a directory.

You can see this for yourself in [the documentation for `mkdir()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir): `man 2 mkdir`:

> The argument *mode* specifies the permissions to use. It is modified by the process's *umask* in the usual way: the permissions of the created directory are (*mode* & ~*umask* & 0777).

The reason is, of course, security. With umask, users have a great deal of control over default permissions (to e.g. block default read permissions for world or even group). If you want files that are sticky, setuid, setgid, group-writable, or world-writable (assuming a `0o022` umask), you need to do this explicitly using a chmod.

Comment: perfect answer, more detailed than the duplicate, thanks :)