# Django created folder can't be removed apache on Centos 7

Tags: python, django, apache, centos7

I have a django application which creates a work directory for a package. This is done with:

```
if not os.path.exists(dest):
            os.makedirs(dest)
```

The creation of the folder works great, but when the django application later try to remove the very same folder, I get "Permission denied".

Apparently the permissions of the folder and files created by django is owned by root and not by apache. Why is it not owned by apache if apache created it? How can I make apache and django to create it as apache?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you
[Permission problems when creating a dir with os.makedirs (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231901/permission-problems-when-creating-a-dir-with-os-makedirs-python)

According to the official python documentation the mode argument of the os.makedirs function may be ignored on some systems, and on systems where it is not ignored the current umask valued is masked out.

Either way, you can force the mode to 0777 using the os.chmod function.

Comment: Thanks, That's certainly a solution, although it would be useful to know or change it to always create files as apache user or group

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the optimal solution is to set the uid that django will use in wsgi.py. By explicitly setting the user to be 'apache' for the current python process, every file that is created belongs to the user 'apache'. I found this out after Nicos Mouzourss answer.

To set the uid:

```
import os, pwd
os.setuid(pwd.getpwnam('apache').pw_uid)
```