# Python: create a directory with 777 permissions

Tags: python-3.x, permissions

I'm making a program that creates a folder using `os.makedirs("foo")`.
But when I open Windows 10 files explorer and right click on the new directory that has been created, I noticed that it was not possible to delete the folder without administrator privileges.
So how do you create a folder with the permission to recursively delete this folder ?

I create the directory using: `os.makedirs("data/base/{}".format(args[0].text), mode=0o777)`

I delete it using:

```
def delete_class(self, *args):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk("data/base/{}".format(self.clicked_class_to_delete.id), topdown=False):
            for name in files:
                filename = os.path.join(root, name)
                os.chmod(filename, stat.S_IWUSR)
                os.remove(filename)
            for name in dirs:
                os.rmdir(os.path.join(root, name))
        shutil.rmtree("data/base/{}".format(self.clicked_class_to_delete.id)
```

)

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you need to do `os.umask(0)` before `os.makedir`, to remove the mask for the current user.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem for me! Could you please elaborate a bit more on what `os.umask(0)` actually does? I am looking in the documentation but I am a bit lost...

Comment: In simple terms, the user mask (umask) restricts the permissions that can be set by the program. Setting umask(0) removes this property, so whatever permissions are set by the program will be directly reflected. In my case, my celery worker was unable to write folders created by my main program unless I did this.

Comment: @GarvitJain your solution is good and work. i noticed that for some reason i can do from the bash shell `mkdir --mode=0777 hello` and this shell command works. so somehow using the shell `mkdir` command works but the python `os.mkdir` does not.

Answer (score 10):

From the documentation: 
`os.makedirs(name, mode=0o777, exist_ok=False)`

You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs).

Comment: I edited my topic with more details, the problem persists

Comment: @MikeDelta, just to be sure - you are able to create the folder and delete it with the code segment that you added, but you can't delete it "manually" without admin permissions. Am I right?

Comment: Sometimes I can't delete it from the file explorer, but often my interpreter gives an error like `OS error: permission denied` or `error: file not empty` or something like this

Comment: @MikeDelta Try to localize the problem. Next time you get the error check if the folder is actually not empty. Need to understand which of your commands failing to be properly executed. You can run your code a few times only with the first `for` loop to see if it's executed properly each time. Then add the second `for` loop. And only then add `shutil.rmtree`

Answer (score 6):

Just do this:

```
os.makedirs(name,0777)
```

Comment: I edited my topic with more details, the problem persists.

Comment: This does not work. You can follow this anwser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67723702/8718377

Answer (score 1):

Time stamped based directory. With full permission.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y%m%d%H%M")
dirName = "/var/name-{}".format(now)
os.umask(0)
os.makedirs(dirName,mode=0o777)
```