# os.makedirs problem when running from Linux centos 7.0 terminal but NOT from python console

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, centos, centos7

I have a python 3 code:

```
system_name = 'myName'
path_perf_folder = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]) + '/' + system_name + '_test/'

try:
    coriginal_umask = os.umask(0)
    os.makedirs(path_perf_folder, 0o755)
finally:
    os.umask(original_umask)
```

The code runs perfectly from python console (running directly os.makedirs command without permission and umask stuff), but when I run from Linux Centos 7.0 terminal or MacOS 10.14.1 terminal it does not work.

I have tried different permissions al well (0o770 and 0o777) but all the time my error is:

```
  File "performance_maker.py", line 130, in <module>
  os.makedirs(path_perf_folder, 0o755)
  File "/shared/centos7/python/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 221, in 
  makedirs
  mkdir(name, mode)
  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/myName_test/'
```

The umask part I c/p from a stackoverflow question but it does not work for me
[here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231901/permission-problems-when-creating-a-dir-with-os-makedirs-in-python/23704144)

Thanks!

Comment: did you print the path you were about to create in both environments and verify that they match?

Comment: When running your script from the command line, argv[0] probably doesn't include the path, just the actual script file name. (Verified on my setup.) Your permission error is happening because your script is attempting to mkdir in the root "/" folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])` will only be a nonempty string if `sys.argv[0]` has a path separator (i.e. '/' for unix-like systems) character in it. Using string operations to construct the path like you do means that you'll try to create the directory under /, which you probably don't have write access to. Instead, you should use os.path.join to construct your path, so that empty strings get handled properly and you get the relative path you want.

Comment: Could please be so kind to type my example using os.path.join to be sure I am right

Comment: @ananvodo just replace the line assigning to `path_perf_folder` with `path_perf_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), system_name + '_test/')`

Answer (score 1):

When run from the command line, your script is probably getting only the filename of the script, not the full path. Therefore, when run at the command line, your script is attempting to mkdir in the root ("/") folder. See below for a quick script you can run to see how your system works.

```
import os, sys

dirname_out = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])

print('sys.argv[0] is     {}'.format(sys.argv[0])) # See difference from REPL and when run as script
print('cwd is             {}'.format(os.getcwd())) # Might be what you want
print('dirname is:        {}'.format(dirname_out))
print('dirname of cwd is: {}'.format(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))) # Not recommended
```

Depending on how you want your script to operate, your solution will vary. I am not sure of your desired outcome as you did not supply the input when you executed your script.

If you want to run the script and always make the new directory in the same directory you ran the script, you probably want to us "os.getcwd()" for creating the base dir.

If you want to provide the location to create the directory, then you probably want to pass the directory to the script by checking, parsing, and constructing from sys.argv[1].