# python script, folder permissions, created a folder with wrong permissions

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, chmod, umask

I have the following function, when I run it, I get the folder created with the following permissions and it's not what I explicitly set:

Code:

```
def copy(src, dst):
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(src)):
        print('No source directory to copy from')
    else:
        if not os.path.isdir(dst):
            print('No destination directory to copy files to')
            print('Creating destination directory')
            os.umask(0o002)
            os.mkdir(dst, mode=0o777)
            print('Destination directory created')
    shutil.copy2(src, dst)
    os.chmod(dst, stat.S_IEXEC)
    os.chmod(dst, stat.S_IXGRP)
    print("copied "+str(src)+" --> "+str(dst))
```

The folder is created with the following:

```
# ls -la /tmp/
total 16
drwxrwxr-x  4 userx  userx  4096 Jul 25 10:21 .
drwxrwxrwt 25 root root 4096 Jul 25 10:21 ..
d-----x---  2 userx  userx  4096 Jul 25 10:21 tmpdir
```

Any ideas?
i.e. the mask on the system is 0022

Comment: what permissions do you expect?

Comment: [Permission problems when creating a dir with os.makedirs in Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231901/permission-problems-when-creating-a-dir-with-os-makedirs-in-python)