# Permission denied on creating a file after os.makedirs even after setting umask(0)

Tags: python

A popular question [Permission problems when creating a dir with os.makedirs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231901/permission-problems-when-creating-a-dir-with-os-makedirs-in-python), as well as  a number of other resources mention setting

> os.umask(0)

before calling `os.makedirs()`.   I have done this, but still have permission denied on creating files in the new directory.

```
BASEDIR="./cdm"
import os
from  pathlib import Path
try:
    original_umask = os.umask(0)
    print("original_umask", original_umask)
    os.makedirs(BASEDIR, mode = 0o777, exist_ok = True)
    print("files: ",[f.name for f in Path(BASEDIR).glob("*")])
    print('perms on dir', hex(os.stat(BASEDIR).st_mode))
finally:
    os.umask(original_umask)
with open(f"{BASEDIR}/xx.yml",'w') as f:
    f.write("hi")
```

Here is the result:

```
original_umask 18
files:  []
perms on dir 0x4177
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './cdm/xx.yml
```

So the perms are not open to the world (*4177*) even after setting `umask(0)`. But that should not matter here since the code creating the new files is in the same process/owner.

I am on `macOS` `Ventura 13.4.1` using `python3.10`

Comment: try mode=0o777 on makedirs

Comment: @Mate  same error

Comment: maybe calling os.chmod(BASEDIR,0o777) after makedirs

Comment: Print statements show the permissions are already 4177 *after* `makedirs`

Comment: Works for me on macOS using Python 3.11.4 installed by Homebrew. There is nothing obviously wrong with your code. What does `ls -ld cdm` output? Have you tried this in a different root dir; e.g., */tmp*?